# Can we change past simple in past perfect in this case?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

The Blind Baron asked me if I was interested in learning drums and I took him up on his offer. I had always wanted to learn how to play, but the opportunity never **presented** itself, and I never **pursued** it.

why it is past simple for presented and pursued? Why it is  not past perfect because this happens before he has learnt and joined the Blind Baron.

I had always wanted to learn how to play, but the opportunity  had never **presented** itself, and I had never **pursued** it until the Baron asked me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tense and aspect are not something that has only one correct form in a given situation.

> *The Blind Baron **asked** me if I **was** interested in learning drums and I **took** him up on his offer. I **had** always **wanted** to learn how to play, but the opportunity never **presented** itself, and I never **pursued** it.*

In this scenario, the reason that ***had wanted*** is used as opposed to ***wanted*** is because you want to make sure that the act of you wanting to learn preceded the act of you taking him up on his offer.

Now, the reason that ***presented*** and ***pursued*** are used instead of ***had presented*** and ***had pursued***, respectively, is because the acts of the opportunity never presenting itself and you never pursuing it do not precede the act of you wanting to learn but follows it.

Still, you can use ***had presented*** and ***had pursued*** to emphasize that these acts precede the act of you taking him up on his offer. But that's not mandatory but optional, because no one would confuse the chronological order of these acts even without the help of the past perfect forms.

When there's no confusion, always go for the simpler form.